# How to migrate protect level build.gradle file from Gradle Groovy to Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to migrate my protect level build.gradle file from Gradle Groovy to Gradle Kotlin DSL. I've watched several tutorials but none of them clearly explain what to change the code to in the project level `build.gradle` file. I only got as far as renaming the file to `build.gradle.kts`.

**Error**

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
> public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: String?): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
> public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: Provider): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = "1.1.1"
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false)
    id("com.android.library" version "7.3.1" apply false)
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.6.10" apply false)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```kotlin
id("com.android.application") version "7.3.1" apply false
```

Explanation:

`version` is defined as `infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: String)`, so it can be called as `id("...").version("...")` or as `id("...") version "..."` but it cannot called on `String`

in your invalid code:

```
id( "com.android.application" /*String*/ version /*??? no String.version*/ "7.3.1" apply false )
```

but valid:

```
id( "com.android.application") /*PluginDependencySpec*/ version /*OK PluginDependencySpec.version*/ "7.3.1" apply false
```

Comment: What about the `compose_version` part? Unresolved reference: ext

Comment: don't sure (cannot check  now) but it seems `extra.set("compose_version", "1.1.1")` or very close to it

Comment: but if your example is full - i don't see any causes to do it in `buildScript`
why not in main body?
```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false)
    id("com.android.library" version "7.3.1" apply false)
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.6.10" apply false)
}
project.extra.set(...)
```